# How to add Parent node to a group of nodes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following input XML and I want to add a parent tag (items)and place all the items inside it ,I am new to XSLT I tried the below Transformation but I am not getting the required output :
**Input.xml**

```
 <rootnode>
     <header>
      <head1>Food</head1>
      <head2>Vegetables</head2>
     </header>
     <item>
      <i1>Tomato</i1>
      <i2>100</i2>
     </item>
     <item>
      <i1>Brinjal</i1>
      <i2>50</i2>
     </item>
     <item>
      <i1>carrots</i1>
      <i2>10</i2>
     </item>
   </rootnode>
```

**My XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/rootnode">
            <rootnode>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </rootnode>
        </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="/rootnode/header">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="rootnode/item">
         <items>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
         </items>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="text()" />

     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output xml:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rootnode xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <header>
            <head1>Food</head1>
            <head2>Vegetables</head2>
        </header>
        <items>
            <item>
              <i1>Tomato</i1>
              <i2>100</i2>
            </item>
        </items>
        <items>
             <item>
               <i1>Brinjal</i1>
               <i2>50</i2>
             </item>
        </items>
        <items>
             <item>
               <i1>carrots</i1>
               <i2>10</i2>
             </item>
        </items>
      </rootnode>
```

**Required output:**

```
 <rootnode>
        <header>
            <head1>Food</head1>
            <head2>Vegetables</head2>
        </header>
        <items>
            <item>
                <i1>Tomato</i1>
                <i2>100</i2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <i1>Brinjal</i1>
                <i2>50</i2>
            </item>
            <item>
                <i1>carrots</i1>
                <i2>10</i2>
            </item>
        </items>
    </rootnode>
```

I want to have parent tag(items) for all the items as a collection but my 
xslt is producing parent tag for every item.Could someone please help me out 
here.

Comment: Michael can u pleas help with this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026336/xml-xslt-transformation-group-address-section-with-parent-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/rootnode">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="header"/>
        <items>
            <xsl:copy-of select="item"/>
        </items>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```