# XML XSLT transformation - Group address section with parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML as below:

```
<root>
<id>1001</id>
<name>Object 1001</name>
<child>
    <a>This is A Level</a>
    <b>This is B Level</b>
    <c>This is detail</c>
    <AddressLine1>A</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine2>Line 2</AddressLine2>
    <City>Any</City>
    <Postcode>1001</Postcode>
</child>
<child>
    <a>This is E Level</a>
    <b>This is F Level</b>
    <c>This is sddetail</c>
    <AddressLine1>X1</AddressLine1>
    <AddressLine2>Line 2</AddressLine2>
    <City>Any1</City>
    <Postcode>1002</Postcode>
</child>
```

And I want XSLT and want XML transformed as below

```
<root>
    <id>1001</id>
    <name>Object 1001</name>
    <child>
        <a>This is A Level</a>
        <b>This is B Level</b>
        <c>This is detail</c>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine1>A</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Line 2</AddressLine2>
            <City>Any</City>
            <Postcode>1001</Postcode>
        </Address>
    </child>
    <child>
        <a>This is E Level</a>
        <b>This is F Level</b>
        <c>This is sddetail</c>
        <Address>
            <AddressLine1>X1</AddressLine1>
            <AddressLine2>Line 2</AddressLine2>
            <City>Any1</City>
            <Postcode>1002</Postcode>
        </Address>
    </child>
</root>
```

I have appended  node as parent to address nodes in child node.

I want to group together address related nodes within address parent node. Collection can contain multiple children hence needed xslt to achieve above response.

Answer (score 0):

You just need something like

```
<xsl:template match="child">
  <child>
    <xsl:copy-of select="a|b|c"/>
    <Address>
      <xsl:copy-of select="AddressLine1|AddressLine2|City|Postcode"/>
    </Address>
  </child>
</xsl:template>
```